# White bar on top of search bar in popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios9

I have this weird top white bar above the search bar(on the right side). When I tap the button again to close the popover it will turn black, so I don't know if it is the popover background color or something else. Also, this happens only on iOS 9 Some help would be much appreciated.

[image]

EDIT: The problem is that I want that white bar removed, not that it's turning black

Comment: Seems you are not the only one with weird iOS9 popover bar behavior: https://twitter.com/steipete/status/643713853407293441

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this same problem, here is how I got rid of that top white bar. I just changed `UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown` to `UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny` where I was doing the `presentPopoverFromRect`